# Can ISPs monitor apps that one uses on iOS?

Tags: network, monitoring

Is it possible for an ISP to identify what iOS app I use based on network traffic?

Answer (score 2):

Your ISP would be able to see what servers the app is connecting to, so most likely yes. If you wouldn't like this to be possible, you can use a VPN to reroute your connection through other computers and make it harder to trace.

Comment: Then ISP also has to know what server refers to what application.